# How to ptrace multi-process or mutli-thread application from Go

Tags: linux, go, ptrace

I am attempting to write a program that would print all of the syscalls a program makes. I am having trouble extending this code to work with multi-processing scripts. I started off with code from https://github.com/lizrice/strace-from-scratch, and now I would like to trace offspring processes as well.

I tried adding the options `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE`, but this causes the process to hang for some reason. I do not know why. If I do not specify these options, then the process runs to completion, but of course children are not traced.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    seccomp "github.com/seccomp/libseccomp-golang"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
)

func init() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
}

func main() {
    var err error

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        log.Fatalf("usage: ./trace-files program [arg]...")
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[1], os.Args[2:]...)
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &unix.SysProcAttr{
        Ptrace: true,
    }
    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error starting command: %s\n", err)
    }
    if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        // We expect "trace/breakpoint trap" here.
        fmt.Printf("Wait returned: %s\n", err)
    }

    pid := cmd.Process.Pid
    exit := true

    var regs unix.PtraceRegs
    var status unix.WaitStatus

    // TODO: Setting these options causes the multiprocessing Python script to hang.
    ptraceOptions := unix.PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK | unix.PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | unix.PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE
    if err = unix.PtraceSetOptions(pid, ptraceOptions); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error setting ptrace options: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("pid\tsyscall")

    for {
        if exit {
            err = unix.PtraceGetRegs(pid, &regs)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
            name, err := seccomp.ScmpSyscall(regs.Orig_rax).GetName()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error getting syscall name for orig_rax %d\n", regs.Orig_rax)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%d\t%s\n", pid, name)
        }
        if err = unix.PtraceSyscall(pid, 0); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error calling ptrace syscall: %s\n", err)
        }
        // TODO: is it OK to overwrite pid here?
        pid, err = unix.Wait4(pid, &status, 0, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error calling wait")
        }
        exit = !exit
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I have written a Python script that uses multiprocessing and prints the process IDs that it spawned.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def fun(x):
    return os.getpid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("PYTHON: starting multiprocessing pool")
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        processes = pool.map(fun, range(1000000))
    print("PYTHON: ended multiprocessing pool")
    processes = map(str, set(processes))
    print("PYTHON: process IDs: ", ", ".join(processes))
```

When I run the Go code above on a single process program, like `ls`, then things seems to work fine.

```
go run . ls
```

But when I run the Go code on the Python script, then the output hangs (but only if I supply the ptrace options I mentioned above).

```
go run . python script.py
```

---

My end goal for this program is to get a list of all of the files a program uses. I will inspect `/proc/PID/maps` for each syscall for that part, but first I would like to know how to trace multi-process programs. I tried looking through the documentation and code for strace, but that confused me further...

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but maybe replace `unix.Wait4(pid, &status, 0, nil)` with `unix.Wait4(-1, &status, 0, nil)` so that it's willing to wait for *any* process, not just the initial process that exec.Command created.